# "correct" way to select next sequence value in HSQLDB 2.0.0-rc8

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hsqldb

suppose i have a sequence, called TEST_SEQ
what would be the correct way of selecting its next value ?
this does not work:

```
select next value for TEST_SEQ
```

probably because it expects a "FROM" clause.
looking at HSQLDialect.getSequenceNextValString() in hibernate i see this:

```
"select next value for " + sequenceName + " from dual_" + sequenceName
```

which in my case would result in something like:

```
select next value for TEST_SEQ from dual_TEST_SEQ
```

which does not work for 2.0.0-rc8 (i only assume this works in pre-2.0 versions - havent verified)
I've come across a solution that involves creating a simple table with 1 row called DUAL, in which case this will work (oracle style):

```
select next value for TEST_SEQ from DUAL
```

but hsqldb does not come with this table out of the box, and im not sure how i can get hibernate to generate such a table on "first boot".

Im thinking there has to be a way to get the next value for a sequence out of the box and im just missing it.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> suppose i have a sequence, called TEST_SEQ what would be the correct way of selecting its next value ?

While the [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html) says:

> The next value for a sequence can be included in SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE statements as in the following example:
>
> ```
> SELECT [...,] NEXT VALUE FOR <sequencename> [, ...] FROM <tablename>;
> ```

the "correct" way (because simpler, because not involving a table like a dumb DUAL table that HSQLDB doesn't have) would be:

```
call NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence_name>;
```

This appeared in [1.7.2](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hsqldb.user/3718) and this is actually how Hibernate handles sequences in the `HSQLDialect` of "recent" versions of  Hibernate Core (see <strike>[HHH-2839](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2839)</strike>).

And indeed, this is what I see in the `HSQLDialect` of `hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar`:

```
public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
    return "call next value for " + sequenceName;
}
```

So my advice is: upgrade to a newer version of Hibernate, you are very likely using Hibernate Core 3.2.5 or prior.

Comment: @hatchetman82 You're welcome. BTW: The common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;)

Comment: @hatchetman82 No problem. It's just that if you consider an answer as a good answer (which is very likely if you accept it), then it makes sense to upvote it IMO, this is how SO works.

Comment: Hi, this may be related. I'm using Apache's DdlUtils to generate the database on startup using this xml for the id: `<column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" />`. What should I be doing to get a new key value when inserting objects? I'm also using iBatis.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently if you run

`SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE` (PGS standing for Postgres)

then you can query it using standard Postgres syntax like `select nextval('sequence_name')`

It even returns nothing for `curval` if `nextval` hasn't been called yet, possibly similar to how Postgres behaves.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html

<s>Also note that if you once do this , typical HSQLDB sequence like `call NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NAME` will no longer work.</s> Seems they still work.

Also note that more "exotic" Postgres stuffs like `select last_value from schemaName.sequence_name` aren't yet emulated/don't work the same (for getting the current value of a sequence regardless of session).

Avoid this message `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTVAL`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hibernate is creating those dual_xx tables on the fly?  Weird.

Anyway, your way seems to work for me with hsqldb 2.3.2:

```
 select next value for <sequence name>;
```

but you can't alias the name, for that I had to do this:

```
  select next value for <sequence name> as <my name>, 3
```

Then the alias worked, no dual needed.  `call next value` I couldn't seem to alias...